# Extending a 2-frame field - manifolds with boundary

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, differential-topology, obstruction-theory

If $M$ is an orientable compact 3-manifold with boundary such that there is defined $s\in\Gamma(\partial M,V_2(TM))$ a section of the 2-frame bundle of $TM$, then $s$ extends to $\tilde s\in\Gamma(M,V_2(TM))$

**Proof:**

*Step 1*

Triangulate $M$. It gives rise to a cell structure on $M$.

*Step 2*

I define $\tilde s=s$ on $\partial M^{(1)}$, the 1-skeleton of $\partial M$.

*Step 3*

I extend $\tilde s$ over $M^{(1)}$, because $\pi_0(SO_3)=0$.

*Step 4*

I then extend it over $M^{(2)}$ (because the obstruction, which is the second Steifel-Whitney class $w_2(M)\in H^2(M,\pi_1(SO_3))$ vanishes for any orientable compact 3-manifold, due to the Wu formula and the vanishing of $w_1(M)$ as $M$ is orientable.)

*Step 5*

Now, having obtained $\tilde s$ in particular on $\partial M^{(2)}$, I can homotope $\tilde s$ to $s$ over $\partial M^{(2)}$, because they already agree on $\partial M^{(1)}$ and the obstruction to homotoping over the 2-skeleton is just $\pi_2(SO_3)$ which is the trivial group.

*Step 6*

Now, having obtained $\tilde s$ over $M^{(2)}$, we extend it to all of $M$, because again, the obstruction to extending over the 3-skeleton is the trivial group $\pi_2(SO_3)$.

I need this reviewed.

Comment: I don't understand Step 3. As the tangential bundle of $M$ is trivial, the datum of a $2$-frame is equivalent to a map to $SO(3)$. Obstructions to extending such a map from the $1$-skeleton to the $2$-skeleton lie in $\pi_1SO(3)$, which is non-trivial.

Comment: Edited and changed numbering. Steifel-Whitney classes and other such characteristic classes help us when we at times encounter such situations as $\pi_1(SO_3)$ being non-zero, and the cohomology group being non-zero.